# each in jquery binds element in order(top to bottom)?

Tags: jquery

i am facing a problem when am trying to bind a array with the ids of my div's i wanted to bind them in order of their appearance staring with first to last..
The code:

```
i=1;
$('.hiddenvalue').each(function(){
   arrayinit[i] = $(this).attr("id");
   i++;
});
```

*but its binding in any random order, why is it so? any suggestions?*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

does this give you the same results ?

```
var arrayinit=[];
$('.hiddenvalue').each(function(){
   arrayinit.push($(this).attr("id"));
});
```

I'm not sure it'll change the order, i think the order is more the same as it appear in the DOM tree does your .hiddenvalue divs appear in the correct order in the DOM tree ?

Comment: thanks upvoted, can i have first array value 1 by default instead of 0??

Comment: arrays allways start at 0 but if you really want to start at one just add a dummy value in first place ie: var arrayinit=[null]; and then ignore the first 0 based item

Answer (score 3):

"i" seems redundant. Try...

```
$('.hiddenvalue').each(function(){
   arrayinit.push( $(this).attr("id") );
});
```

Answer (score 1):

try this one instead

```
$('.hiddenvalue').each(function(i){
   i++;
   arrayinit[i] = $(this).attr("id");
});
```

However, I'm not quite sure why is it happening.